# What's the best way to return a subset of a list

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a list of tasks. A task is defined by a name, a due date (and time) and a duration.

My TaskManager class handles a `std::list<Task>` sorted by due date. It has to provide a way to get the tasks due on a specific day.

An example : I have task 1 due on Monday 6 am, task 2 due on Monday 9 am, task 3 due on Tuesday 7 pm. If I pass "Monday" to my method, it should return tasks 1 and 2.

How would you implement that ?

I think a good way (from API point of view) would be to provide a `std::list<Task>::iterator` pair. So I would have a `TaskManager::begin(date)` method. Do you think this method should get the iterator by iterating from the start of the list until it finds the first task due on that date, or by getting it from a `std::map<date, std::list<Task>::iterator>` (but then we have to keep it up-to-date when adding or removing tasks) ?

And then, how could I implement the `TaskManager::end(date)` method ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of using a `std::list`, consider using a `std::set` or `std::map`, which can keep the items in a sorted order without additional effort.  Then you can find the items due on a particular date using `std::set::lower_bound` or `std::map::lower_bound`.

Comment: I have to keep the items sorted by hours and minutes, but my method should return the tasks due on a particular *day* (i.e. I have tasks due tomorrow at 2 pm and 5 pm, and I ask "Hey give me all the tasks due tomorrow" to my class :) ). So I can't use a `map<date_time, task>` and its `find` method, or even a `multimap<date, Task>` and its `equal_range` method.

Comment: If they are sorted by date-time, then you can use `std::set::lower_bound` to find iterators the first entry from today, and the first entry from tomorrow, in O(log n), and iterate over that range for just the entries for that corresponding days.

Answer (score 1):

Finding an item on a sorted sequence can take `O(log n)`, while your method would take `O(n)`.

If to build your collection you've got already sorted items use an `std::vector`: it will cost `O(1)` to push any item at the end and you'll be able to use a binary search to locate your item in `O(log n)`.

Otherwise (if you insert items in random order) use a `std::map` (using your dates as key) or a `std::set` to both add and search items in `O(log n)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator adaptor. Basically this is an iterator whose constructor takes another iterator as an argument, and whose advance method advances that iterator until it finds a value meeting some condition, then returns that value or some value calculated from it.